# download file are not working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I try different methods but it's not working.

```
 function download($id)
{
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $fileinfo = $this->profile_model->download($id);
    $file = 'uploads/'.$fileinfo['file_name'];
    force_download($file, NULL);
    

 }   



   public function do_upload()
    {
            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 100;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }
    }   


  }
?>
```

**profilemodel.php**

```
 public function download($id)
     {
          $query = $this->db->get_where('upload_cv',array('id'=>$id));
          return $query->row_array();
       }
```

> A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Profile_controller::$profile_model
>
> Filename: controllers/profile_controller.php
>
> Line Number: 137
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
> E:\xampp\htdocs\jobportal\application\controllers\profile_controller.php
> Line: 137 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: E:\xampp\htdocs\jobportal\index.php Line: 315 Function:
> require_once.
>
> > A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function download() on null
>
> Filename: controllers/profile_controller.php
>
> Line Number: 137
>
> Backtrace:

Answer (score 0):

The error says

> Undefined property: Profile_controller::$profile_model

which means you are using in your controller Profile_controller `$this->$profile_model` either without having loaded the model:

```
$this->load->model('Profile_model');
```

or either the function load(), the class or the filename do not start with a capitalized `P`.

as a result, you get the 2nd error

> Call to a member function download() on null